# Why the validation errors dont appear?

Tags: laravel

I have this function below to update the email of an authenticated user.

The issue is that if there are validation errors, the custom messages are not appearing in the view.

Do you know why?

```
public function updateEmail(Request $request){

    $rules = [
        'email' => 'required|email'
    ];

    $customMessages = [
        'email.required' => 'The email field is required.',
        'email.email' => 'Please insert a valid email.'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $customMessages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#loginData');
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->email = $request->email;

    $user->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Email updated with success.');

    return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#loginData');
}
```

View:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="loginData" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
    @include('includes.errors')
    <form method="post" action="{{route('user.updateEmail')}}">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" value="{{$user->email}}" class="form-control" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label>Email</label>
                <button>Update Email</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You aren't flashing the error messages to the session, you are redirecting directly to a new url

Comment: Thanks, this url "if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#loginData');
    }" is the url where the user updates the email.

Comment: use this  if($validator->fails()){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }

Comment: Thanks, it works with that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#loginData');
    }
```

Change to this, so that you can return the errors in the session and use {{$errors->first}} or foreach loop through them with $errors->all() as $error

```
if ($validator->fails()) {

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

In laravel 5.6, when using the withErrors method, the $errors variable will automatically be shared with your view after redirection.